# «Взвейтесь, соколы, орлами»

Tags: грамотная-речь, поэзия

Всегда озадачивался этой строчкой из песни: "Взвейтесь, соколы, орлами".

Если они соколы, то зачем им взвиваться орлами? Нет, я понимаю, что "соколы" — это обращение, эпитет, но все равно звучит забавно. Если уж они соколы, пусть соколами и взвиваются. А вы что думаете по этому поводу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Русская народная песня: "Взвейтесь, соколы, орлами. Полно горе горевать!То ли дело под шатрами В поле лагерем стоять.Слава матушке - России, Слава русскому царю, Слава вере православной И солдату молодцу".

Орел - царь птиц, символ могущества,поэтому его изображали на государственных гербах.
 К концу 15-го века на печатях Российского государства закрепились два
изображения: с одной стороны был всадник, поражающий змея, с другой – двуглавый
орел. В переносном смысле орлом называли гордого, смелого, сильного человека с  "орлиным взором".

Сокол тоже гордая и независимая птица, но не символ власти, говорили, например: "Гол, но сокол". Издавна соколов приручали и охотились с ними на мелких животных (соколиная охота).Сокол — символ смелости и отваги, храбрости и отчаянности. Как правило, эти качества приписывают в первую очередь воинам, а потому сокол — олицетворение войны.

http://slovari.yandex.ru/~книги/Символы,%20знаки,%20эмблемы/Сокол/

http://epatrina.narod.ru/et18.doc

Интересно вспомнить, что Сталин очень любил Красную Армию вообще, а летчиков в особенности. Красных лётчиков называли «сталинскими соколами» и «ястребками».

Answer (score 1):

Да вроде тут все проще...
Сокол и орел - разные птицы. И повадки у них разные. И хотя их часто путают, за ними стоит разный ассоциативный ряд.

Соколы - традиционный эпитет для солдат, видимо связан с соколиной охотой: солдаты служили царю-батюшке, как сокол- хозяину. То есть соколы - это всего лишь солдаты.
А вот с орлами - интереснее. Орел в отличие от сокола - даже при охоте на хозяина (да-да, охота с орлами тоже была и, что интересно, тоже считалась "соколиной") гораздо решительнее и беспощаднее атакует добычу. И зрение у него считается лучшим. Ну и летает по поверьям выше (хотя на самом деле и то, и другое - спорно). Ну вот с учетом всего этого и этот пернатый оксюморон не выглядит таким уж странным.

Ну а если добавить, что слова песни, судя по всему, канонизировались относительно недавно, можно предположить, что неизвестный автор известного текста просто не слишком озабочивался тем, как это будет воспринято.